# Do teleporters exist in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

[Star Trek relies on them all the time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_%28Star_Trek%29) but are there any teleporters in the Star Wars universe? And if not, why not? Did George Lucas ban them?

Comment: At least one fanfic has handled the lack as being a result of the fear of cloning tech - transporters don't move you, they duplicate you, which may be too close to cloning for SW characters to be comfortable with.

Comment: @Jeff - I thought Star Wars was [all about clones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_of_the_Clones). Surely the Galactic Empire would jump at the chance to use transporters if they cloned?

Comment: After the Clone Wars, public sentiment swung WAY away from clones.  Even the Empire couldn't have put down the riots that would have ensued if they'd used transporters to create clones...not to mention that transporters don't **typically** do that.

Comment: Star Wars took place *a long time ago in galaxy far, far away.* Obviously this teleporting stuff is *futuristic*, where Star Trek takes place.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There was no "Technological" teleportation in Star Wars Universe.

Instead there was <strike>Magical apparation</strike> ... errr ... wrong Wikia ...

There were two (possibly related) instances of **Force-based** teleportation:

1. [Fold Space](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fold_space) ability

   > Fold space was a Force power that allowed a Force-user to bend space to instantly transport an object between places. This form of teleportation was used by the Aing-Tii, a mysterious species living on a planet in the Kathol Rift. This technique allowed the wielder to use the Force to teleport any object from one place to another.

   First appearance: Zahn's "Vision of the Future" (1998) but NOT named till 2001 " Jedi Academy Training Manual"
2. Unnamed "[Force teleport](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teleport)" - "a rare force ability that enabled the user to move from place to place almost instantaneously".

   - > An'ya Kuro (aka " Dark Woman") "was a very powerful Jedi and was known to possess many Force powers uncommon among the Jedi, such as the ability to control plant matter, and bend light around her to render herself invisible. She even appeared to be able to pass through solid objects. She also possessed the ability to use the Force to teleport
   - > [Abeloth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Abeloth) was extremely powerful, and evaded Luke Skywalker via disappearing.
   - > Darth Phobos may have also possessed this ability (no source on Wikia so not certain)
   - > Some of Palpatine's Force Adepts who guarded his museum and vaults also had this ability.

   Appearances: "Star Wars: Republic: Emissaries to Malastare"; "Star Wars: Empire at War: Forces of Corruption"

Answer (score 13):

In the Expanded Universe video game "Star Wars: The Old Republic" set a thousand years before the movies, there is an experimental teleporter that is being tested on the planet Belsavis.

It instantly transports living beings with everything on them (clothes, weapons, etc.) over short distances to other similar transporter terminals.

The technology is described as experimental in the game. No explanation was given to how it works. And nowhere is it later referenced if the technology moved beyond the prototype stage or if it was deployed anywhere else besides select locations on Belsavis.

[image: transporter on Belsavis]

Comment: The wiki article with a more in depth discussion is available at http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter

Answer (score 11):

Luke mentions teleportation in A New Hope to C-3P0:

"Not unless you can alter time, speed up the harvest or teleport me off this rock."

Surprised no one has mentioned this.

Comment: The way he said it implies that (he believes that) teleportation is impossible, or at least implausible.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a teleporter in the classic *Star Trek* beaming sense, but by the literal definition of the word, a teleporter is used in the Dark Horse comic *Boba Fett: Bounty On Bar-Kooda*. A magician named Magwit uses a 'short-range matter transmitter'. By all appearances, space is folded between separate devices, allowing for the user to instantaneously move from Point A to Point B by walking through one side and out the other.

In the story, Magwit had stolen it from 'a rather strange alien' and incorporated it into his act. One device was on stage, the other hidden away in back. No one was aware how his 'mystifying hoop trick' worked, indicating such technology was entirely unheard of in the Rebellion and New Republic eras, when Magwit was performing.

Answer (score 3):

### YES

Teleporters have always existed in Star Wars, since less than a year after the release of *Star Wars (1977)*, the film that would become *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*.

Teleportation was introduced in the Marvel Comics serial published in Pizzazz Magazine #6 (March 1978), in the “Keepers World” story which ran from Pizzazz #6-10.
[image: Pizazz]

[“Do You Know Where Your Children Are? (Keeper’s Workd Pt. 1) From Wookia:](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Do_You_Know_What_Your_Children_Are%3F)

> Luke Skywalker, Leia Organa, C-3PO, and R2-D2 escape Imperial stormtroopers by teleporting into the Keeper's Temple, where they are confronted by four mysterious children with the power to control the elements. Before they can question the children further, the stormtroopers manage to activate the teleportal and continue the chase.

The Keeper was revealed to be a powerful droid, and its teleportation was technological.

Teleportation would become a staple within the Star Wars expanded universe, canon as well as legends, both technological as well as Force powered.

### Other examples for completeness:

From @DVK-on-Ahch-To answer:

- **Fold Space:** First appearance: Zahn's "Vision of the Future" (1998) but NOT named till 2001 " Jedi Academy Training Manual"
- **Unnamed "Force teleport":** "a rare force ability that enabled the user to move from place to place almost instantaneously". Ex. Dark Woman, Aboleth, Darth Phobos, Palpatine’s Force adepts.

From @Mufasa answer:

- **Star Wars The Old Republic:** Belsavis Prison teleporters. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter

From @Gungai answer:

- **Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope:** Luke snidely references teleportation.

From @User33616 answer:

- **Boba Fett: Bounty On Bar-Kooda:** Magwit’s “short-range matter transmitter.”

### In Current Canon

From @NKCampbell comment:

- **The World Between Worlds**:

> In canon, I think the closest would be the World Between Worlds seen in *Rebels*.

From @Geneworm:

- **Star Wars Episode IX: The Rise of Skywalker:**

> In the rise of skywalker we also see two examples of teleportation between Rey and Kylo when they are able to retrieve items off each other despite being far apart

Comment: "Teleportation would become a staple within the Star Wars expanded universe, canon as well as legends, both technological as well as Force powered." I don't think any of the things you've cited are or ever were canon. Also - it was Luke that referenced teleportation, not Threepio. Threepio responded "I'm not very knowledgable about such things." In canon, I think the closest would be the World Between Worlds seen in Rebels. - https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/World_Between_Worlds

Comment: When LFL had a canon “hierarchy,” through the 00’s Marvel was canon, just lowest level. Belsavis prison was canon for a short while before the 2012 Legends apocalypse.

Comment: In the rise of skywalker we also see two examples of teleportation between Rey and Kylo when they are able to retrieve items off each other despite being far apart

Comment: Obviously there's been a lot of drift from the original story with telekinetic knights with laser swords that could lift rocks if they concentrated to folks folding the spacetime continuum and other excesses that would be fine in other SF but don't really match the feel of original Star Wars.

Comment: "The ability to destroy a planet is insignificant next to the power of The Force.” “Judge me by my size, do you?”… Part of Star Wars has been Star Wars trying to blow up expectations of close-minded limits from the very beginning.