# Is this an example of teleportation in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

I just read *Dawn of the Jedi* #6: *The Prisoner of Bogan*, Part 1 and I'm a little confused.

During one scene the three main characters are training with wooden staves in a snowy training area with an Noghri master named Tave. He appears to disappear, and then Sek'nos Rath replies "That's the trick I want to learn". Did this Tave guy teleport?

Comment: See related question about Star Wars teleportation: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9387/397

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes and no.

Yes, there is a [teleportation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teleporter) in Star Wars (main article [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teleport)).

No, Noghri (master martial artists able to hold their own against Luke Skywalker when they are first introduced) are simply *that* good at movement and stealth, to effectively seem to be able to disappear.

Comment: Oh that's right.