# On which planets is C-3PO knowledgeable about time manipulation and teleportation?

Tags: star-wars

In A New Hope, Luke and C-3PO have this exchange:

> **C-3PO:** “Is there anything I might do to help?”
>
> **Luke:** “No, not unless you can alter time, speed up the harvest, or teleport me off this rock.”
>
> **C-3PO:** “I don’t think so, sir. I’m only a droid, and not very knowledgeable about such things. Not on this planet anyway[...]”

To me this raises an obvious question: on which planets *is* he knowledgeable about such things?

Is this just idle chatter, or is there any media that has C-3PO involved in time manipulation or teleportation?

Comment: I read that as mostly a nod to "it's a big universe out there;" an aside that hints at a broader and deeper background the audience simply hasn't been shown yet.

Comment: related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9387/do-teleporters-exist-in-star-wars

Comment: @DavidW Sure, that’s the purpose of the line in the film, but that’s not my question. This is a franchise that decided that the random C-3PO looking droid in the background of the first scene was a secret agent for the empire, and gave a whole tragic backstory to the stormtrooper who’s only line in the film is “Look sir, droids!”. I was asking if there’s been anything hung off this rather juicy statement from a main character. To be fair, I’ve been watching this movie since I was 10, and only just noticed it yesterday, but I’m still surprised.

Comment: Note that you've picked the two least plausible statements out of a list of three. "Not unless you can speed up the harvest" ... "Not on this planet anyway" would be a much less interesting interpretation.

Comment: @IMSoP if Luke means “speed up the harvest” in a purely practical sense, then C-3PO saying that he doesn’t think he can brings up its own problems. Owen purchased him for exactly that purpose in the previous scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a fair bit of reading today on the relevant works, and while it doesn't look like there are any time travel stories directly involving C-3PO, I was surprised that there's actually 2 straightforward answers in the Canon:

## Alderaan (or On board the Tantive IV)

[Time Travel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Time_travel) and [Teleportation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Teleporter) are rare, but both are possible in the Star Wars universe.

C-3PO's primary function is "etiquette and protocol", and he is the personal property of Bail Organa, Prince of Alderaan. We see protocol droids performing hospitality duties similar to what you might expect personal assistants or hotel staff to do, such as [TC-14](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TC-14) in The Phantom Menace.

So if Luke had asked the same question(or any other question) at C-3PO's "day job" of facilitating diplomacy for the Alderaanian royal family, C-3PO most likely could have directed him to someone better equipped to answer the question, or an archive where he could research it himself.

## Lothal

There is a means of manipulating time and travelling through space in the [Jedi Temple](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lothal_Jedi_Temple) on Lothal.

Not long before A New Hope the Emperor expended considerable resources trying to control this means of time travel.([Star Wars Rebels: A World Between Worlds](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_World_Between_Worlds))

C-3PO's other job at the time of A New Hope is working for the Rebel Alliance. We see C-3PO as R2-D2's cover story while on a secret mission in [Star Wars Rebels: Droids in Distress](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Droids_in_Distress), and we see the two of them in the hangar on Yavin 4 in Rogue One.

The idea that there are planets on which time travel is possible (or at least that the Emperor believes that there is) would therefore not be surprising to him, as a translator for one of the Founders of the Rebel Alliance.